# Multipart/form-data in Angular 8 Upload

Tags: angular, file-upload, multipartform-data, angular8

I'm trying to create an Angular 8 application that will upload a CSV to a Web API for processing.

contact.component.html file:

```
CSV File: <input type="file" (change)="fileChange($event)" placeholder="Upload file" accept="*.csv" /><br /><br />
```

contact.component.ts file:

```
fileChange(event) {
        const fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
        if (fileList.length > 0) {
            const file: File = fileList[0];
            const formData: FormData = new FormData();
            formData.append('uploadFile', file, file.name);
            this.criContactsService.upload(formData)
                .subscribe((res: any) => {
                    this.toaster.showToast('success', 'Saved', 'CSV has been uploaded.');
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        this.router.navigateByUrl('/pages/community-resources');
                    }, 4000);
                },
                error => {
                    this.logger.error(error);
                    this.toaster.showToast('error', 'Error', error);
                },
            );
        }
    }
```

cri-contacts.service.ts file:

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from './../../../environments/environment';
import { ICRIContact } from './../interfaces/cri-contact.interface';

@Injectable()
export class CRIContactsService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getAll(): Observable<Array<ICRIContact>> {
        return this.http.get<Array<ICRIContact>>(`${environment.apiEndpoint}/cricontacts`);
    }
    download() {
        return this.http.get(`${environment.apiEndpoint}/cricontacts/download`, { responseType: 'text' });
    }
  upload(param: any) {
        return this.http.post(`${environment.apiEndpoint}/cricontacts/upload`, param);
    }
}
```

Server code:

```
[Route("api/cricontacts/upload")]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Upload()
        {
            //Check if user has permission for this operation
            Enums.Role role = JwtManager.GetRole(Request);
            if (role != Enums.Role.SuperAdmin)
            {
                return Unauthorized();
            }

            if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent()) //Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent() always returns false
            {
                return BadRequest(); //Always returns this, BadRequest()
            }
            //Rest of the code isn't relevant
```

What I expect is the file to be uploaded and get a 200 response.  However, I get a 400 response saying bad request.  This line in the server code

```
Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent()
```

always returns false.  I thought using FormData in Angular will set the mime type to be multipart/form-data.  I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Can you verify if the xhr upload request has a Content-Type header with value multipart/form-data

Comment: I checked the request header.  The content-type is application/json.

Comment: You know what the issue could be - I'm using a token interceptor for authentication that sets the content-type to application/json charset=utf-8.

Comment: That's the issue the content-type must be set to multipart/form-data. Either you force the content type in your code or you exclude the upload url in your interceptor to not add the application/json header for the upload request

Comment: Michael Desigaud - that was the issue.  Thanks